# Squarefree Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, square-free

Let $F_n$, $n\geq 0$, be the sequence of Fibonacci numbers, where $F_0=F_1=1$ and $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. A number is squarefree if it is is not divisible by the square of a prime number.

**Question**: Are there infinitely many squarefree Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: I think this an open problem,but from what I just checked in the internet there is no conjecture which says: 
"There are infinitely many square free Fibonacci numbers".I would be surprised if someone has proved something like this and we did not know.

Comment: This is almost surely true, but as with all similar problems about sequences as sparse as the Fibonacci sequence, it's very hard to prove

Comment: Usually Fibonacci numbers are defined with $F_0=0$.

Comment: Squarefree Fibonacci numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A061305

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the traditional definition with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$.

Most likely there are infinitely many squarefree Fibonacci numbers. A simple way to construct them is to consider a subsequence $F_p$ for prime $p$. Notice that if $q^2\mid F_p$ for some prime $q$, then $q$ must be a [Wall-Sun-Sun prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%E2%80%93Sun%E2%80%93Sun_prime), whose existence is a big open question (and even if they exist, they would be very rare).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'very rare'? Are they conjectured to have density zero among the primes?

Comment: Again, this is most likely the case. At least the current empirical evidence suggests so.

Comment: Evidently none are known and there are none up to $1.9 \cdot 10^{17}$

Answer (score 2):

For prime $p$, let $M(p)$ be the least positive $n$ such that $p^2 \mid F_n$.  Then $p^2 \mid F_n$ iff $M(p) \mid n$.  Thus at most $N/M(p)$ of the first $N$ Fibonacci numbers
are divisible by $p^2$.  If we could prove that $\sum_p 1/M(p) < 1$, then  at least a positive fraction of all Fibonacci numbers will be squarefree.
Well, it seems to be true numerically; I don't know if it's provable.

Comment: $M(p)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A065106

Comment: Maybe one can try to determine the least $\alpha$ such that $\sum_{p}p^{-\alpha}<1$, and then prove that $M(p)>p^{\alpha}$.